# Which methods in the 3.5 framework have a String.Format-like signature?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, string

I just noticed that I can do the following, which came as a complete surprise to me:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", "foo", "bar", "baz");
```

This works for the `Write` method too. What other methods have signatures supporting this, without requiring the use of `String.Format`?

`Debug.WriteLine` doesn't...
`HttpResponse.WriteLine` doesn't...

*(And on a side note, I could not find a quick way of searching for this with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). What is a good way to search for specific signatures?)*

**Edit:**

Specifically for the 3.5 framework.

Comment: Not directly related to your question but most `ToString()` methods will also accept formatting and can be faster than the `String.Format` method.

Comment: It would be nice to see this implemented in C#: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-20.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of methods that support this throughout the framework. All subclasses of TextWriter (and therefore [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) and [StringWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringwriter.aspx) and their subclasses) will inherit the [Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2t77weh.aspx) method that supports this.

Another example that is often used is [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx).

You can write your own methods to support this too. You can do it by having an overload with a format string parameter and another parameter with the `params` keyword, like this:

```
public void Foo(string message) {
    // whatever
}

public void Foo(string format, params string[] arg) {
    Foo(string.Format(format, arg));
}
```

Comment: *There are a lot of methods* - such as? That **is** the question :)

Comment: @Orbman: Sorry! That's true, but others have already suggested about 4 more good answers and I don't want to just plagarize everyone else's answers into my post. Instead I tried to come up with some new and related information that might be useful to you or someone else here. :)

Comment: @Orbman: If you put 'TextWriter' into Reflector you get a lot of matches, most of which probably support this.

Answer (score 4):

StringBuilder instances have an AppendFormat method.

StringWriter instances have a Write overload which takes format parameters.

Comment: Interesting how they used a separate method name for this, I assume because otherwise it would collide with the `(String, Int32, Int32)` signature. Makes me wonder why they did not standardize on this approach for consistency, and make a `Debug.WriteLineFormat` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Debug.WriteLine(string, params Object[] args)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153(VS.95).aspx) overload does this as well, being added in .Net 4.0.

Comment: That seems to be supported in .NET Framework 4 only. Does not work in 3.5.

Comment: @OrbMan - Good catch, added that to the description.

Answer (score 0):

The StringBuilder class has a method called AppendFormat which behaves in the same way