# What is C# analog of C snprintf()?

Tags: c#, c, translation, printf

What is C#   analog of C snprintf()?

In [C code here we use](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/api-example_8c-source.html)

```
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), outfilename, frame);
```

What could be its exact analog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>[`StringBuilder.AppendFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdekwk0b.aspx)</strike> [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) is the closest. It performs the same operation, but do note that the format strings are [in a different format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx).

Using `String.Format`:

```
string buf = string.Format("{0}", frame);
```

Using `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendFormat("{0}", frame);
```

Answer (score 3):

The most basic version is [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

```
string result = String.Format(format, arg0, arg1, ..., argn);
```

But many other classes support something similar, including all classes that derive from `TextWriter`. There are some examples in this question [Which methods in the 3.5 framework have a String.Format-like signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274467/which-methods-in-the-3-5-framework-have-a-string-format-like-signature)

- `Console.Write`
- `StreamWriter.Write`
- `StringWriter.Write`
- `StringBuilder.AppendFormat`
- many more...

Answer (score 0):

If you're assigning to a string, use String.Format

```
var newString = String.Format("Number: {0}", 10);
```

If you're looking to append a ton of strings, use the StringBuilder.AppendFormat.  It'll save you in the long run because they can be chained, saving space.

```
var result = new StringBuilder().AppendFormat("{0}", 10).AppendFormat("{0}", 11).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

> What could be its exact analog?

There is no exact analog, because:

1. strings in C and C# are implemented differently. In C, strings are mutable arrays of chars, while in .NET they are immutable object instances. So in .NET you don't "write to a buffer" as `snprintf` does, you just create an entire new string
2. the format strings used in .NET (in `String.Format`, `Console.WriteLine`, etc) are very different from C (different placeholder format)

As mentioned in other answers, the closest equivalent is `String.Format`, but it's definitely not an exact analog